# I want to make toggle between two screen by get of Sharedprefrences in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-bloc

I have a Flutter application where I want to toggle between two screens based on a value stored in the Shared Preferences. I am using the Cubit package for state management. Currently, the app always shows the `NewsScreen` with the category model set to "sports" even if the value in the SharedPreferences is different.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```dart
// HomeScreen
// ...

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});
  static const String routeName = 'homeScreen';

  List<CatergorieModel> categories = [
    CatergorieModel(
      name: 'Sports',
      image: 'assets/images/sports.png',
      id: 'sports',
      color: const Color(0xffC91C22),
    ),
   // ... more of Categroies
  ];
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<NewsCubit, HomeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/pattern.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, SearchScreen.routeName);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ],
              title: Text(
                NewsCubit.get(context).catergorieModel == null
                    ? 'News App'
                    : NewsCubit.get(context).catergorieModel?.name ??
                        'News App',
                style:
                    GoogleFonts.exo(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
            drawer: DarwerWidget(
              makeModelNull: NewsCubit.get(context).makeModelNull,
            ),
            body: NewsCubit.get(context).catergorieModel == null &&
                    CasheHelper.getData('news') == null
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Pick your Category \n of your intrest',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                                    childAspectRatio: .79,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 18,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 18),
                            itemCount: categories.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return GridViewItemWidget(
                                  OnClick: NewsCubit.get(context).onClick,
                                  index: index,
                                  catergorieModel: categories[index]);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                : const NewsScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

 
}

  onClick(CatergorieModel catergorieModel) {
   
    CasheHelper.saveData('news', this.catergorieModel!.id);
    emit(NewsView());
  }


}

// NewsScreen


class NewsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = 'news_screen';

  const NewsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          NewsCubit()..getSources(NewsCubit.get(context).catergorieModel?.id ?? 'sports'),
      child: BlocConsumer<NewsCubit, HomeState>(listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is HomeLoadindState) {
          const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (state is HomeSorcesErrorState) {
          const Center(
            child: Text('No News'),
          );
        } else if (state is HomeSorcesSuccessState) {
          NewsCubit.get(context).getNewsData();
        }
      }, builder: (context, state) {
        var cubit = NewsCubit.get(context);
        return Column(
          children: [
            const TabBarWidget(),

            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: cubit.articlesList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ArticlesNewsWidget(
                    articles: NewsCubit.get(context).articlesList[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
            )

            // Expanded(
            //   child: ListView.builder(
            //     itemCount: cubit.articles.length,
            //     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            //       return ArticlesNewsWidget(
            //         articles: NewsCubit.get(context).articles[index],
            //       );
            //     },
            //   ),
            // )
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
 
  }
}
```

I expect the `NewsScreen` to show the data based on the value stored in the SharedPreferences. However, it always displays the "sports" category.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the `NewsScreen` display the correct category based on the value saved in the SharedPreferences? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

looks like in the `NewsScreen` you secondly create new instance of the `NuewCubit`:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          NewsCubit()..getSources(NewsCubit.get(context).catergorieModel?.id ?? 'sports'),
      ...
```

So, you don't need the `BlocProvider` here, you already created `NewCubit` above in the widget tree and you just need to consume it, e.g. with `BlocConsumer`.
Moreover, you won't need shared prefs, because you could store choosen category in the  cubit state and get it from there. More info in [bloc documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts).